# Grafana: duplicate Legend and Graph for Rate Query after Pod Restart

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I want to show the rate of logins per hour in a web app. This is the PromQL query I have:

```
rate(logins_total[1h])*3600
```

The situation in the database is that there has been a restart of the pod running the webapp and there was one login after the restart.

If I show the last hour, then the graph looks fine. But if I show the last 3 hours, then the legend is duplicated as well as the graph (see screenshots). I do realise that there are now two time series, one for the old pod and another for the new pod. What I would like to show is just one graph and one legend.

So basically the second screenshot should look like the first - is that possible at all?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the query into [sum](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) aggregate function in order to merge multiple series into a single one:

```
sum(rate(logins_total[1h])*3600)
```

P.S. It may be more clear to use [increase](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#increase) instead of `rate` multiplied by time range in seconds:

```
sum(increase(logins_total[1h]))
```

P.P.S. note that `rate` and `increase` in Prometheus may return unexpected results over slow-changing integer counters because of the following issues:

- [extrapolation](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/3746)
- missing increase between the last raw sample just before the lookbehind window specified in square brackets and the first raw sample in the lookbehind window. See [these docs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y2Mp041_2v0blnKnZk7keCnJZICeK2YWUQuXH_m4DVc/edit).

Both issues are resolved in VictoriaMetrics - this is Prometheus -like monitoring solution I work on. See [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) docs for details.

Comment: Thank you, the sum-function is indeed what I was looking for. For some reason it is not documented under https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/

Comment: The `sum()` function is named as `aggregate operator` under Prometheus docs - see https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators